# Multi threading object access

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have two questions regarding multi-threading in C#.

My program has scripts, and I'm using the LuaInterface project to load them and execute them. I want to run the scripts on different threads, so I did the following:

```
new Thread(() =>
{
    using (Lua lua = new Lua())
    {   
        Script script = new Script(character, this.ID);

        lua.RegisterFunction("sendMessage", script, typeof(NpcScript)
            .GetMethod("SendMessage"));

        lua.LoadFile(@"Scripts\" + this.Script + ".lua").Call();
    }
}).Start();
```

So this should run the script on a different thread. The Script object is also assigned to the character object. Character class has the following:

```
public Script Script { get; set; }
```

Script's class strucutre is so:

```
public class Script
{
    public Character Character { get; private set; }
    public int ID { get; private set; }
}
```

The method sendMessage uses a ManualResetEvent to return a boolean type value. The main program thread sets the value and then sendMessage returns it (sendMessage blocks the current thread until the response is set by the main thread).

However, I'm facing two dilemmas.

**1.** If the main thread will set the response of the Script object, wouldn't that give me an exception (as I'm accessing it from the main thread)?

**2.** What happens if the script thread accesses the character object assigned to it, and the main thread also accesses it?  Wouldn't it collide?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. No. An exception will only occur when you attempt to access a control from a thread that does not "own" the controls' handle. You are not working with a Windows control here so there is no need to worry. 2. Maybe. It is difficult to say without a clear explanation of the nature of the script / `Character` type.

Comment: @ByteBlast What do you need to know?

Comment: just a remark: you should name your script "CharacterScript". Currently its Character Context is hidden and would mislead people to think you could also use it for a CarScript or whatever

Comment: 2. If no synchronization is implemented anywhere outside of Script class, then you should implement synchronization in Script or in Character class manually to avoid collisions.

Answer (score 0):

As @ByteBlast said, since you are not working with UI (forms, controls, etc.) there is no risk of an exception. However, @sasha_gud is right when he says you should implement synchrization to avoid problems since you havee two thread accessing the same object. The simplest thing to do here would be to use a `Lock`.